# What does the phrase 'speak of' mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

In this following context, what does the phrase ''speak of'' mean?

I found thi definitions of ''speak of'' as:
''serve as evidence for something. (Oxford Languages)

''speak of something) to seem to prove that something exists or is true''
(Macmillan Dictionary)

Should I use this meaning in this context?

the context:

> But where there is no real unchanging entity, no soul, there one
> cannot speak of the transmigration of such a thing.

Source:
Page. 8
''Fundamentals of Buddhism''
by Nyanatiloka Mahåthera

Comment: I think it's the basic meaning _talk about, refer to_.

Comment: It's not rocket science! It just means if we accept that souls don't exist, then it's meaningless to talk about the transmigration of souls.

Answer (score -1):

I think the quotation can be paraphrased as

> If there is no soul then one cannot prove the existence of transmigration.

So the second definition, Macmillan, seems to fit the quote better.